# To detect clicks in AngularJS, do I use a directive or a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

I want to track all clicks on an `a`, `button` and `input[type="submit"]`

It makes sense to me to use a controller attached to the body tag. I need to track every click and date and time stamp each. I have the API ready to do it, but I can't figure out how to listen to the clicks.

I thought a controller would be a good way to do it, but some stuff I've read has been to use a directive. Basically turn the body tag into a directive.

That doesn't really make sense to me, but I'm new at this.

And, in either case, how do I detect the click? I'm trying to use the directive below, but it's not firing. Says it can't find `domElement`

Here's my directive. If I do it this way, won't I need a controller to write the click to my API?

```
'use strict';

var loggerDirectives = angular.module('loggerDirectives', []);

loggerDirectives.directive('loggerdirective', function () {

  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      // Get a reference to the button DOM element
      var clickedDOMElement = document.querySelector(['a, button, input[type="submit"']);

      // Wrap it as a jqLite element
      var clickedItem = angular.element(domElement);

      var onItemClick = function () {
        // Do something
        conlsole.log('Clicked');
      };

      clickedItem.on('click', onItemClick);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        clickedItem.off('click', onItemClick);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: it is likely that it can't find `input[type="submit"'`.  try adding the closing `]` inside the `' '`.

Comment: should probably be doing this as a single directive at top level of body and use a single  delegated event handler that checks each target. Note that you need to loop results of your `querySelector` and any elements not in view at that time won't be included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the 'listen' directive to all you elements you want to listen to.

```
var loggerDirectives = angular.module('loggerDirectives', []);

loggerDirectives

.directive('listen', ['listenService', function (listenService) {

  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {

      element.on('click', function(){
         //Do you stuff here
         listenService.yourFunction();
      });
    }
  };
}]) //You can use your API in a service, here called listenService. It is used in the directive

.service('listenService', function(){
    this.yourFunction = function(){
      //execute your API here
    };
});
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! That is awesome. Thanks for the fix, and it works great.

Comment: actually, one more question. How would i get at the id attribute? I'm assuming the directive will pass it to the service. I'm trying the following right now `var id = angular.element().attr('id');` but that keeps rendering undefined.

Comment: A little more detail. I've since learned that the `element` that is being clicked is the body tag. So how do I get to the child that is being clicked?

Comment: 'element' represents the DOM element you've put the attribute directive on. If you need the id use `attr.id`

Comment: I need the id of the CHILD element that I actually click on. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh wait, are you saying add this directive to all elements I want to track?

Comment: Yes. Is it a problem for your use case?